# Why in my android application, it's so slow to `mkdirs` on sdcard?

Tags: android, performance, file-io

There is a `mkDirs` method in my code of android application, which is simple:

```
public static File mkDirs(File dir) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
        System.out.println("*** mk dir, cost: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
    }
    return dir;
}
```

I called it many times in my application to create directories on the sdcard, the path is based on `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

And this is the log:

```
11-09 21:40:18.002: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 2181ms
11-09 21:40:20.504: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 1629ms
11-09 21:40:20.570: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 36ms
11-09 21:40:20.635: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 38ms
11-09 21:40:20.697: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 35ms
11-09 21:40:20.760: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 38ms
11-09 21:40:20.827: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 34ms
11-09 21:40:20.909: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 52ms
11-09 21:40:20.970: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 35ms
11-09 21:41:17.433: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 24184ms
11-09 21:42:42.570: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 1593ms
11-09 21:44:26.709: INFO/System.out(28259): *** mk dir, cost: 1254ms
```

You can see sometimes it is very fast, but something is very slow -- which is more than 20 seconds.

I think it may be caused by the ram, which maybe not enough: 512M, and there are also some other applications running on the background.

So I reboot my phone and relaunch the application, and here is the log:

```
11-09 22:17:27.680: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 1983ms
11-09 22:17:35.138: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 2752ms
11-09 22:17:36.020: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 37ms
11-09 22:17:36.080: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 34ms
11-09 22:17:36.159: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 54ms
11-09 22:17:36.221: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 38ms
11-09 22:17:36.281: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 34ms
11-09 22:17:38.294: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 1988ms
11-09 22:17:39.499: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 413ms
11-09 22:17:39.577: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 49ms
11-09 22:18:41.583: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 810ms
11-09 22:18:46.768: INFO/System.out(1000): *** mk dir, cost: 811ms
```

It's much better this time, you can see the max time is less than 3 seconds.

And I test it on another android pad which has 1G ram, and the log is:

```
11-09 21:58:36.770: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 2ms
11-09 21:58:36.949: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 3ms
11-09 21:58:37.027: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 2ms
11-09 21:58:37.035: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 1ms
11-09 21:58:37.035: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 1ms
11-09 21:58:38.723: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 2ms
11-09 21:58:38.730: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 2ms
11-09 21:58:38.754: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 1ms
11-09 21:58:38.770: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 1ms
11-09 21:58:38.785: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 1ms
11-09 21:58:38.855: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 5ms
11-09 21:58:38.887: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 2ms
11-09 21:58:38.926: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 7ms
11-09 21:58:38.934: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 1ms
11-09 21:58:38.949: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 2ms
11-09 21:58:59.871: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 4ms
11-09 21:59:06.176: INFO/System.out(13647): *** mk dir, cost: 7ms
```

You can see it always fast.

I also tested my sdcard by an android sdcard-testing application, the write speed is 3.x M/s, and read speed is 7.x M/s, which is fast enough.

So I guess the reason is: if the ram is not enough, IO operation will be very slow sometime, is it true?

---

UPDATE: I just rewrite this question, removed those unnecessary information.

Comment: SD card performance is categorized by class, not capacity. So "8G sdcard" tells nothing useful. And how many cards **and** devices have you tested prior drawing any conclusion?

Comment: "it usually cost 20 seconds" -- how many different devices did you test against to arrive at your "usually" conclusion? Also, is this truly an SD card (i.e., something you can remove), or is this merely external storage (i.e., something that you can mount on a host PC)?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com but 20sec is extremely slow even for a class 2 card, i know coz i have one.

Comment: @OP its possible that there's something wrong with your sdcard, try testing the read/write speeds while its mounted on pc, also check whether the data you write to it gets corrupted

Comment: I just rewrite this question, removed some unnecessary information

Comment: What I am telling you is you should check your card in different device **and** different card in your device. Then come back asking here about something more precise than "slow". Now you are just purely guessing based on nothing and nobody would be able to tell you more now than "yes, it is slow".

Comment: There's a Note on the `StricMode` docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) that might explain part of this problem. Not sure how it's related with the available ram (if it's really related).